# Only show elements who has some propertie Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing a Vue app and I have a list of movies like this:

```
movies [
  {name: 'spider-man', id: 3},
  {name: 'thor'},
  {name: 'x-men', id: 7}
]
```

and this is my template

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.name">{{movie.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I only wanna show the movies who has an ID, in this case, thor shouldn't be shown. I've tried with v-if but I got this error: "The 'movies' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'".
Thanks, hope you can help me!

Comment: `movies.filter(m => 'id' in m)` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties to the rescue:

```
data: () => ({
  movies: [
   {name: 'spider-man', id: 3},
   {name: 'thor'},
   {name: 'x-men', id: 7}
  ]
})
...
computed: {
  moviesWithId() {
    return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.id)
  }
}
...
```

In your template

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="movie in moviesWithId" :key="movie.name">{{movie.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may add condition to render to your li tags like v-show="movie.id"

Or filter your dataset like :

```
<li v-for="movie in movies.filter(movie => movie.id)" :key="movie.name">{{movie.name}}</li>
```